# Unused cable sitting in terminal block inside switch box

Tags: electrical, switch, light, cables

I have a cable inside the wall box of a light switch in the UK and it is not connected to anything but it is live. The wires are sitting inside plastic connector/strip. Upon opening up the connector, I found that none of the wires were stripped back. Black wire reads about 150 V ac to earth on the same cable and I believe the reason for this is poor earth connection on the other end at junction box. Should I remove this "unused" cable while I still have my floor boards lifted for safety reasons?

[image: old junction box]

[image: light switch box]

Comment: Are you saying that the gray cable containing a red & black wire is the "random" one? Odds are good that it serviced _something_ in the past that has since been removed. There's probably no great value in removing it, but knowing where it goes (and figuring out why it only measures 150v to... ground maybe?) would be a good thing. Then label it for future use.

Comment: Depending on your meter, the 150V reading may be just induced voltage from actual live conductors adjacent to the cable and a meter with high input impedance not drawing any current to speak of.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. Yes black wire to earth on the same cable shows 150 V.

Comment: Added picture of some kind of old junction box? This is where the cable is leads to

Comment: I believe the answer to why it shows 150 V is the earth is not properly connected on this box. Is this unsafe?

Comment: You're not asking a clear question here (or you're asking _three_ questions). I revised your title to actually ask one, but you should revise again if that's not what you want to know. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Which wires aren't stripped, and why would you expect them to be? All the ones that need to be stripped that I can see, are.

Comment: Agree with @kreemoweet. In the original pic (now the 2nd one), the wires don't appear to be stripped because they're _properly_ stripped - There is bare wire under the terminal screws, but the visible portion is insulated all the way into the terminal. The new pic shows bare wire sticking out of the terminals. If that was left that way in the US, it shouldn't pass inspection because there is bare wire showing outside the connectors.

Comment: The wires that are not stripped are the black and red wires inside the switch box that are sitting inside the plastic connector. Now I know the answer is the cable has no use in the current set up so someone just left it there because it was plastered in. However it is still live as it is connected to the junction box under floor boards. My ultimate question is should I bother diaconnecting this cable from the junction box for safety reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two wires haven't been stripped, and have been shoved into a terminal block, then they must be spare wires.  Presumably they used to do something.  By shoving them into a terminal block, it keeps them safe, so they can't touch anything else.

If you're certain they are no longer needed, then you could remove them, but you would have to work out where they go first.